# Use of ?noredirect=1&isuserentityoverride=1

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, user-record, custom-link

Can you please explain me the use of setting `noredirect=1` and `isUserEntityOverride=1` and appending it to the url.

I'm creating a custom link in Lightning which will open the user record.
If I set `noredirect` to 0 or skip it then the link doesn't seem to work - opens up the user record page for a moment and then redirects to the profile page of the user in Lightning.

Also, I don't see any effect of appending `isUserEntityOverride=1` in the URL. The user record page opens up anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its not clear how you are attempting to redirect users, normally, you shouldn’t need to build the url and use it to navigate, but instead, should use navigation events

Comment: Hi glls - Thanks, I'm trying to create a custom link on User Profile layout which will open related user detail page. This custom link will be working similar to 'User Detail' button present in User Profile Page.